# Google Maps API Android Location

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Как переместить значок локации на google карте в другое место?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте [хак](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36787406/3212712) с нахождением кнопки в `MapView` и изменения её `LayoutParams`

```
View locationButton = ((View) mMapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
// position on right bottom
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
rlp.setMargins(0, 180, 180, 0);
```